# Connecting SAP BO to Snowflake to import data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, webi

I have a requirement to import data to Snowflake from SAP BO (WEBI) system.
I know the other way round can be done that is getting Snowflake data to SAP BO. But how do I connect the SAP BO system to Snowflake to get data into Snowflake.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 basic options:

1. Use an ETL tool/process - but recommendations for tools are out of scope for this forum
2. Copy the data to a Snowflake-supported cloud file systems (e.g. AWS S3) and use COPY INTO to load the data from there to Snowflake

However, my understanding is that SAP BO is a data visualisation tool and as such it connects to data sources to visualise the data those sources contain; therefore SAP BO doesn't hold any data - so I'm not sure what data you're trying to load into Snowflake from SAP BO. Are you trying to load data that is held in a data source that SAP BO is connecting to - in which case you need to get that data from that source and not via SAP BO?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! To be precise,  I want to load statistics data (Report execution data) from WEBI to Snowflake which I guess can be found in the Audit database. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Now to get this data into Snowflake I am trying to find how we could connect to SAP BO system from Snowflake.

Comment: OK - that makes sense. The options I outlined in my answer still stand